# SQL split CSV values to rows in denormalized table

Tags: sql, csv, database-normalization

So I have some quite large *denormalized* tables that have multiple columns that contain comma separated values.

The `CSV` values vary in length from column to column. One table has 30 different columns that can contain CSV's! For reporting purpose I need to do a count on the CSV values for each column (essentially different types)

Having never done this before what is my best approach?

1. Create a new table using a CSV split method to populate and have a
   type field and type table for the different types?
2. Use the XML approach using XPath and the .nodes() and .value()
   methods to split each column on the fly and perform  a count as I go
3. or should I create some views that would show me what I want.

Please advise

Comment: You can done above task using any computer  language e.g. java/php

Comment: How about SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)?